Implementation of pointnet++
This is my error. The shape of the mask tensor does not match the shape of the tensor being indexed. Specifically, the mask tensor has a shape of [8, 512, 3], while the tensor being indexed has a shape of [8, 512, 16]. How to resolve this?
/usr/bin/python3.10 /home/aniruddha/PycharmProjects/Pointnet_Pointnet2_pytorch/centerline_pn.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aniruddha/PycharmProjects/Pointnet_Pointnet2_pytorch/centerline_pn.py", line 265, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/aniruddha/PycharmProjects/Pointnet_Pointnet2_pytorch/centerline_pn.py", line 217, in main
    outputs, _ = model(points)
  File "/home/aniruddha/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1532, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aniruddha/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aniruddha/PycharmProjects/Pointnet_Pointnet2_pytorch/models/pointnet2_cls_msg.py", line 32, in forward
    l1_xyz, l1_points = self.sa1(xyz, norm)
  File "/home/aniruddha/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1532, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aniruddha/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aniruddha/PycharmProjects/Pointnet_Pointnet2_pytorch/models/pointnet2_utils.py", line 283, in forward
    group_idx = query_ball_point(radius, K, xyz, new_xyz)
  File "/home/aniruddha/PycharmProjects/Pointnet_Pointnet2_pytorch/models/pointnet2_utils.py", line 148, in query_ball_point
    group_idx[mask] = group_first[mask]
IndexError: The shape of the mask [8, 512, 3] at index 2 does not match the shape of the indexed tensor [8, 512, 16] at index 2

Process finished with exit code 1


def query_ball_point(radius, nsample, xyz, new_xyz):
    """
    Input:
        radius: local region radius
        nsample: max sample number in local region
        xyz: all points, [B, N, 3]
        new_xyz: query points, [B, S, 3]
    Return:
        group_idx: grouped points index, [B, S, nsample]
    """
    device = xyz.device
    B, N, C = xyz.shape
    _, S, _ = new_xyz.shape
    group_idx = torch.arange(N, dtype=torch.long).to(device).view(1, 1, N).repeat([B, S, 1])
    sqrdists = square_distance(new_xyz, xyz)
    group_idx[sqrdists > radius ** 2] = N
    group_idx = group_idx.sort(dim=-1)[0][:, :, :nsample]
    group_first = group_idx[:, :, 0].view(B, S, 1).repeat([1, 1, nsample])
    mask = group_idx == N
    group_idx[mask] = group_first[mask]
    return group_idx

def square_distance(src, dst):
    """
    Calculate Euclid distance between each two points.

    src^T * dst = xn * xm + yn * ym + zn * zm；
    sum(src^2, dim=-1) = xn*xn + yn*yn + zn*zn;
    sum(dst^2, dim=-1) = xm*xm + ym*ym + zm*zm;
    dist = (xn - xm)^2 + (yn - ym)^2 + (zn - zm)^2
         = sum(src**2,dim=-1)+sum(dst**2,dim=-1)-2*src^T*dst

    Input:
        src: source points, [B, N, C]
        dst: target points, [B, M, C]
    Output:
        dist: per-point square distance, [B, N, M]
    """
    B, N, _ = src.shape
    _, M, _ = dst.shape
    dist = -2 * torch.matmul(src, dst.permute(0, 2, 1))
    dist += torch.sum(src ** 2, -1).view(B, N, 1)
    dist += torch.sum(dst ** 2, -1).view(B, 1, M)
    return dist


